# Overriding main CSS of an element without having to reset each property

Tags: html, css

If a selector has a long list of properties stored in main.css and I wish to use just one property and override it in custom.css how can I "reset" that element without having to list all those properties in main.css and set them to default?

I have always had an issue with CSS interfering and always having to reset them to width:auto etc if they are no longer needed.

https://jsfiddle.net/ugdh833a/1/

```
     // Stored in main.css, this stylesheet is not to be edited
     #header {
              height: 100px;
              overflow: auto;
              width: 960px;
              padding: 10px;;
              margin-bottom: 7px;
              padding-bottom: 4px;
              position: relative;
              z-index: 99;
          }

    // Stored in custom.css, this page is used to overide the main css page if required
    // I now wish to just set this selector with just one property, how can I reset this without having all the above at default levels eg. width:auto, padding:0; etc

            #header {
            float:left;
          }
```

Comment: You should use JavaScript for dynamically adding, deleting and altering style attributes.

Comment: just add (!important) at the end of the css rules you want to change -- https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: I cannot add !important as that property was not defined in main.css - All the main.css will still interfere with the single property I now require

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately you would have to override each property in your custom.css if you didnt want to change the markup or you could add another class and use the `:not()` selector

The new custom header (you will need to add `class="alternative"`):

CSS:

```
#header:not(.alternative){
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 960px;
    padding: 10px;;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
 }


#header.alternative{
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with   `all:initial;` , it's for all properties with the exception of  `unicode-bidi` and `direction`. see these details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/all

here a snippet:

```css
/*Stored in main.css, this page is not to be edited*/
#header {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 960px;
  padding: 10px;;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  border:1px solid red;/*added to better illustrate all:initial*/
  background:silver;/*added to better illustrate all:initial*/
}


/* Stored in custom.css */
#header {
  all:initial;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
test
</div>
```

Comment: Adding all:initial still leaves legacy properties for that selector when I tried it in Google developer tools. Here is an example of Chrome Dev Tools results and the legacy stylesheet.css still active https://jsfiddle.net/a62152ww/

Comment: custom.css should be after main.css/stylesheet.css or I'm missing something else ? https://jsfiddle.net/grassog/njhvex7h/1/